# Office error after server upgrade

Tags: windows-server-2008, microsoft-office-2007

I have a problem that I am stumped on..

I upgraded my server 2003 to server 2008 enterprise. So far I am only having one problem..

All my programs work besides office 2007. When I click on it it asked to go int safe mode and if I click yes or no it wont load up. I`ve uninstalled and re installed number of times.

Here is the error in the event log

Faulting application WINWORD.EXE, version 12.0.4518.1014, time stamp 0x45428028, faulting module unknown, version 0.0.0.0, time stamp 0x00000000, exception code 0xc0000005, fault offset 0x00000000, process id 0x1094, application start time 0x01cfc4792cfd93d5.

any help would be great..

Thanks

Comment: Microsoft no longer provide mainstream support for either Office 2007 or Server 2008. This is very old technology!

Answer (score 0):

Apply all available service packs to your server.

Apply all available Windows updates to your server.

After installing any applications such as Office, apply all available service packs for them too.